# Can't create azure storage container with python

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I followed the azure tutorial in order to upload photos in an azure account storage : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage/

This is my code (exactly the same than the tutorial) :

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
from azure.storage.blob import PublicAccess


class UserPhotoBlobStorage():

    ACCOUNT_NAME = "account_name"
    ACCOUNT_KEY = "account_key"

    def __init__(self):
        self.block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=UserPhotoBlobStorage.ACCOUNT_NAME,
                                                   account_key=UserPhotoBlobStorage.ACCOUNT_KEY)
        self.block_blob_service.create_container('mycontainer', public_access=PublicAccess.Container)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    storage = UserPhotoBlobStorage()
```

But when I execute it I have this following exception :

[image: Exception]

Can somebody explain me what is the problem ?
I contacted the azure support which told me that they couldn't do anything for me ...

In addition, I'm using the recommended python package in the tutorial : https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python with the latest version.

Comment: My guess is that you're providing improper account key. Can you share the value you pass in `account_key=UserPhotoBlobStorage.ACCOUNT_KEY`? **IMPORTANT: PLEASE DO NOT SHARE THE ACCOUNT NAME**

Comment: @GauravMantri is correct: either your account name or key is incorrect. I just ran your exact code with no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is related to your account key being incorrect. The Azure storage key is base64-encoded. The string you provided (`"account_key"`) is not properly base64-encoded, hence the `Incorrect padding` error. Try running this again with the full account key (either primary or secondary) provided within the portal.

Comment: I regenerated a new set of keys and now it works fine. 
Thank you everyone

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please either mark this answer as such, to properly close the question.